# ruby on rails setup on my ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualhost

Do I need to set up virtual hosts as mentioned here: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/deployment/apache-passenger

I am just setting up dev env on my own machine to try and learn ruby on rails.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Just run script/server from your Rails app's main directory.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [script](http://github.com/sleepycat/wrong-side-of-the-tracks) to set up a Rails development env in Ubuntu. It might be worth a look.
You don't need to install a server. As mentioned above, open a terminal window and cd to your project directory. In Rails 3 you type "rails server", for any other version of Rails its "script/server". That will launch the default webbrick server on localhost:3000.